# Application deployment over EKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, devops, amazon-eks

I am trying to deploy my application over EKS cluster using AWS codepipeline. I have already created a building job using the builspec.yml to push the docker image to ECR repo. Now I am trying to deploy the image to container over EKS cluster. I am following the below steps However facing below challenge:

```
1)    - CREDENTIALS=$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::7*********4:service-role/codebuild-CI- 
       Build-service-role --role-session-name codebuild-kubectl --duration-seconds 900)
      - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="$(echo ${CREDENTIALS} | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId')"
      - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="$(echo ${CREDENTIALS} | jq -r '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey')"
      - export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="$(echo ${CREDENTIALS} | jq -r '.Credentials.SessionToken')"
      - export AWS_EXPIRATION="$(echo ${CREDENTIALS} | jq -r '.Credentials.Expiration')"
```

Here in the above step, I am passing the AWS code build role.

```
2) aws eks update-kubeconfig --name $EKS_CLUSTER_NAME --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION

3) - ROLE="    - rolearn:arn:aws:iam::7********4:role/service-role/codebuild-CI-Build-service-role\n      username:build\n      groups:\n        - system:masters"
   - kubectl get -n kube-system configmap/aws-auth -o yaml | awk "/mapRoles:\|/{print;print \"$ROLE\";next}1" > /tmp/aws-auth-patch.yml
   - kubectl describe configmap -n kube-system aws-auth
```

This step is done to update the role in the AWS config auth.

However, I am getting the error:
`error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)`